# Black cattleya pseudobulb

Tags: pruning, orchids, rot

[image]

I would like to ask if I need to prune off the blackened pseudobulb on this cattleya orchid or could I just leave it as is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does not look good but it is a large part of the plant so I think I would leave it and hope for the best. I have a much larger cattelaya and it will get a black part about once a year which I cut off . Mine is over 20 years old, I have sprayed it with fungicide but it does not seem to make a difference.